# How to scan all records with filters using Dynamoose

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, dynamoose

I am trying to search for a word all records available using Dynamoose.
I tried the code below, but to no avail...

```
let buscarEmails = async (email, sistema) => {
  createDynamooseInstance()
  const Email = dynamoose.model('enviar_email', enviarEmailSchema.enviarEmailSchema)

  const filter = {
    FilterExpression: '#destinatario = :email',
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
      '#destinatario': 'destinatario'
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':email': email
    }
  }

  const options = {
    'all': { 'delay': 0, 'max': 99 }
  }

  const buscarEmails = Email.scan(filter).all().exec().then(function (emails) {
    return emails
  })
    .catch(function (err) {
      return err.toString()
    })

  return buscarEmails
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code and it worked fine:

```js
let buscarEmails = async (email, sistema) => {
  createDynamooseInstance()
  const Email = dynamoose.model(process.env.TABELA_EMAIL_ENVIAR, enviarEmailSchema.enviarEmailSchema, { update: true })

  const buscarEmails = Email.scan('destinatario').eq(email).where('sistema').eq(sistema).all(0, 0).exec().then(function (emails) {
    return emails
  })
    .catch(function (err) {
      return err.toString()
    })

  return buscarEmails
}
```